# Frustration at trying to output two specific values from an Array

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I am doing my head in trying to do a simple retrieval for specific arrays within a script so I have an original associative array:

```
$vNArray ['Brandon']  = $item[3]; 
$vNArray['Smith']= $item[4]; 
$vNArray ['Johnson']= $item[5];
$vNArray ['Murphy']= $item[6];
$vNArray ['Lepsky']= $item[7];
```

Which outputs a common result for most values:

```
foreach ($vNArray as $key => $value){

 if(!empty($value)){
    $result  .= "\t\t\t\t<li><strong>$key</strong>"  .$value.   "</li>\n";
 }
```

But then I want two of these arrays to render differently so I added another script suggested by someone:

```
$display_id=array('Brandon', 'Murphy');

foreach ($vNArray as $key => $value){
  if(!empty($value)){
    //Looks into the display_id array and renders it differently
    if (in_array($key, $display_id)) {
    $result  .= "\t\t\t\t<li id=\"$key\"><strong>$key</strong>$value</li>\n";
    } else {
    $result .= "\t\t\t\t<li><strong>$key</strong>$value</li>\n";
    }
  }
```

}

The problem is that i want the result for these arrays to contain both within the first result but when I tried to output 
    $result  .= "\t\t\t\t**$key[1]**".$value[1]." \n";

PHP thinks that the index is the value's character index, so I'm having major syntax issues like id="/" **r**.

I have also tried

```
$result  .= "\t\t\t\t<li id=\"". $display_id['Brandon']$value.\""><strong>$key[1]</strong>". $display_id['Murphy']$value." </li>\n";
```

But I am still getting wrong syntax issues...like

```
syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE
```

Or some other error like this.

Could someone please help?

EDITED

---

I have made the syntax corrections but I still need to specify the index:

The result from

```
result  .= "\t\t\t\t<li id=\"". $display_id['Brandon'] . $value."\"><strong>" .   $key[1] . "</strong>". $display_id['Murphy'] . $value." </li>\n";
```

Needs to be (Note how each value is on the same output depending on what I'm targeting):

```
<li id="Brandon Value"><strong>Brandon</strong> Murphy Value</li>
```

Right now it ignores the index value of . $display_id['Brandon'] . $value. or . $display_id['Murphy'] . $value." all together and just repeats:

```
<li id="Brandon Value"><strong>Brandon</strong> Brandon Value</li>
<li id="Murphy Value"><strong>Murphy</strong> Murphy Value</li>
```

Comment: you accepted no answers at all your questions...

Comment: I don't understand what you want? Can you give an example of the situation?

Comment: "the result for these arrays to contain both within the first result" doesn't make clear sense to me. Please rephrase.

Comment: "Or some other error like this." Could you clarify this?

Comment: @dnl: SERIOUSLY: this dude has asked 8 questions so far and has accepted exactly ZERO answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `$key`, forget the `[1]` bit. Same with `$value`.

Answer (score 0):

Each value needs to be concatenated with another, so for example:

```
echo $a . $b . $c . $d . $e;
```

Notice the `.` contact that joins each variable with the the next / prev variable, so your line:

```
$display_id['Brandon']$value
```

should look like:

```
$display_id['Brandon'] . $value
                       ^
```

I would do the following though.

```
$result  .= sprintf('<li id="%s"><strong>%s</strong> %s</li>',$display_id['Brandon'] . $value,$key[1],$display_id['Murphy'] . $value);
```

Also using sprintf also make your code more readable.

Comment: Please see my edited answer above, you just don't seem to be able to get the EXACT placeholder for each value Brandon or Murphy by targeting them directly.

Comment: @horation/dnl BTW I don't know how you define 'half-accepting' answers because so far non have been answered, not because people aren't helping but because one thing leads to another do if are going to be pedantic at least tell me how to "mark" accepted if that makes you feel better.